# Activiti using receiveTask to pause and resume an activiti

Tags: java, vaadin7, activiti

I am new to the Activiti framework. Learning the concepts via prototypes.

Here is the prototype I am currently working with:

1. I have integrated Activiti with a Vaadin Project
2. Activiti version: 5.16.1

Here is my process flow:
[image: pause and resume]

My main Vaadin java class starts this process flow. The first service task is the `ModalWindow` java class. At this point I add a `subWindow` using
`UI.getCurrent().addWindow(modalWindow);`

This Window has a `TextField` and a submit button. At this point I would like the process to wait for the user to click on submit button.

#### What I have tried so far :

1. added a `ReceiveTask` between `ModalWindow` and `TempTask`.
   this receive task would be signalled to end in the `Button.ClickListener` of the `ModalWindow` class.

#### What happened:

1. Once the `subWindow`  was added to my main page, the process just continued till `endEvent`, skipping over `TemTask`.
2. when User clicked on submit, the entire process was started from the beginning!!

#### What is required:

- On ButtonClick how do I "unpause" the process and continue onto the TempTask class?

Could someone please guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using a user task.
As soon as the user task is initiated, the process will enter a wait state until the task is explicitly completed using the task.complete() API.

Your VAADIN application can automatically wait for the task to be assigned (look at some of the task unit tests for examples of how to do this) and then enable the submit button.

BPMN and Activiti is extremely powerful but sometimes there are many ways to do the same thing.

Let me know if you need any more help.

Cheers,
Greg Harley - BP3

Comment: :) thank you. I used receive task. I will try this method as well